# GeoWebCache throwing an error 400: All backends (1) failed. Last request: when trying to send a WMS service request

Tags: geoserver, wms, extents, geowebcache

We have a stand alone GeoWebCache (version 1.18) that is connected to a GeoServer (version 2.16.0). The data source for the layer in GeoServer is from PostGIS. Recently we are experiencing an issue where in if we send a WMS request to GeoWebCache, it throws an error.

```
400: All backends (1) failed. Last request:'http://*servername*:8080/geoserver/wms?'
```

Here is an example of the service request:

```
https://*servername*/geowebcache/service/wms?service=WMS&version=2.0&request=GetMap&layers=*layername*&bbox=-12503874.838186786,4960457.388858138,-12494090.898563793,4970241.328481132&width=256&height=256&srs=EPSG:3857&format=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile
```

If we try to request in EPSG:4326, the error is different:

```
400: X,Y values for the tile index were calculated to be {769.9999997724444, 1486.4759872853333} which had to be rounded to {770, 1486} and exceeds the threshold of 10%. Perhaps the client is using the wrong origin ?
```

Upon further investigating the issue we found out that when GeoWebCache sends the request to GeoServer, it does not use the same min/max bounding box as defined for that layer in GeoSever.

For example, if we publish a service with data source from PostGIS on GeoServer with min/max bounding box of *-136.097427368164,28.8160457611084,-70.327880859375,58.095703125*, the GeoWebCache has the following properties in the WMS GetCapabilities XML for that service:

```
<BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3857" minx="-2.003750834E7" miny="0.0" maxx="0.0" maxy="2.003750834E7"/>
<BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:4326" minx="-180.0" miny="-90.0" maxx="0.0" maxy="90.0"/>
```

Notice that the maxx and miny in the above properties is 0.0. Due to this the bounding box of GeoServer and GeoWebCache misalign and we get the errors.

I have checked the gridsets in GeoServer for EPSG:3857 and EPSG:4326 and the min/max bounding box and resolutions look correct.

Is there a way or any setting that we need to change so that GeoWebCache picks up the correct bounds? Or is there some other way around to fix this issue?

Comment: You appear to be using the WMS integration mode which is always tricky, your best bet is to make use of WMTS rather than trying to stitch the tiles back together.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! However, I am relatively new to GeoWebCache. Can you please tell me what the service request for WMTS will look like? An example of the URL.